# Why are null values fetched from ADO Recordset instead of correct ones depending on the order of retrieval? (The DB table has NTEXT values)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datetime, vbscript, ado

I have a DB table with two *datetime* nullable columns that I need to read from an ASP page using VBScript.

This is the code I wrote:

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Prepared = True
    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM storico_corsi WHERE stc_id = 5 "
    Set rs = .Execute
    Response.Write("stc_scadenza = {" & rs("stc_scadenza") & "}, ")
    Response.Write("stc_inizio = {" & rs("stc_inizio") & "} ")
    If IsEmpty(rs("stc_inizio")) Then
        Response.Write("- ERROR!")
    End If
End With
```

This code gives this output:

```
stc_scadenza = {19/04/2014}, stc_inizio = {} - ERROR!
```

If I swap the order of retrieval to

```
...
    Response.Write("stc_inizio = {" & rs("stc_inizio") & "}, ")
    Response.Write("stc_scadenza = {" & rs("stc_scadenza") & "} ")
...
```

this is the (correct) result I get:

```
stc_inizio = {19/02/2014}, stc_scadenza = {19/04/2014}
```

Why is a small change in the order of retrieval of elements from an ADO Recordset delivering a completely different outcome?

Please notice that I'm using the Italian locale (*dd/mm/yyyy*) and that `stc_inizio` and `stc_scadenza`, while being often set to midnight timestamps, are of SQL type *datetime*.

---

**UPDATE #1**: I made the code simpler and clearer by reducing the code to the manipulation of just two fields, adding the emptiness check and removing JSON stuff altogether. Some comments below refer to previous, more complicated, versions.

---

**UPDATE #2**: If I replace the SQL query with

```
SELECT stc_inizio, stc_scadenza FROM storico_corsi WHERE stc_id = 5
```

or

```
SELECT stc_scadenza, stc_inizio FROM storico_corsi WHERE stc_id = 5
```

it works properly! But why? This is the DB table I'm using:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[storico_corsi] (
    [stc_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [stc_id_ute] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [stc_utente] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [stc_anagrafica] [ntext] NULL,
    [stc_id_can] [bigint] NULL,
    [stc_canale] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [stc_FE_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [stc_quest_finale] [ntext] NULL,
    [stc_quest_corretto] [ntext] NULL,
    [stc_reg_fad] [ntext] NULL,
    [stc_inizio] [datetime] NULL,
    [stc_scadenza] [datetime] NULL,
    [stc_terminato] [char](1) NULL
        CONSTRAINT [DF_storico_corsi_stc_terminato_1]  DEFAULT ('N'),
    [stc_fine] [datetime] NULL,
    [stc_tempo] [bigint] NULL 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_storico_corsi_stc_tempo]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [stc_data_in] [datetime] NULL 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_storico_corsi_stc_data_in_1]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [stc_progressivo] [int] NULL,
    [stc_anno] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_storico_corsi] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([stc_id] ASC) 
WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) 
ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

---

**UPDATE #3**: The issue can be reproduced anytime I include any of the 3 *ntext* columns in the query. If I don't `SELECT` them, nothing bad happens. Apparently, *ntext* values break the record, but they also do that in an unpredictable way that depends on the order of retrieval of other fields.

---

**UPDATE #4**: BLOBs/*ntext*s have to be fetched last with ADO. This statement sounds a bit crazy but this is what I found here: http://p2p.wrox.com/sql-server-2000/3211-cant-pull-data-ntext-field-into-recordset.html#post78234 It's consistent with my experience.

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious, is there definitely only one row in the database where `stc_id` is 5?

Comment: Yes. I checked right now. :-)

Comment: Okay. So, first thing to do is eliminate the possibility that it's that (custom?) jsArray class causing problems. If you just print out the value of `rs("stc_scadenza")` with your original code, does it have a value, or is it null?

Comment: Right approach. No, the problem is apparently not due to the JSON stuff. If I check `rs("stc_inizio")` with `IsEmpty`, it gives `True`.

Comment: And presumably if you use SQL Server Management Studio and do a `SELECT stc_inizio FROM storico_corsi WHERE stc_id = 5`, you see the expected result?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I did. I get _2014-02-19 00:00:00.000_ in the graphic tool.

Comment: Also, just as a sanity check, what values do you get if you change your original code to simply select a single row, e.g. `SELECT * FROM storico_corsi WHERE  stc_id = 5`? That would eliminate any strange happenings from prior or subsequent loops...

Comment: Correct. Still the same. Actually I might update the question to remove extra stuff that gets in the way of understanding the core issue and make it easier to pin it down to the critical point, let me try.

Comment: OK, now it's really really simple.

Comment: And now it's really, really weird. Okay, last request: try to eliminate the use of your custom json object completely while still reproducing the problem. Because if you can't do that, then there's something quite odd going on in the code inside the json object, and we'll need to see that to figure things out.

Comment: It's getting crazy. :-) Check the last version, no JSON, no mess, just the plain madness of order-dependence.

Comment: Okay, one last sanity check. Do you still get the same result with `SELECT TOP (1) stc_scadenza, stc_inizio FROM storico_corsi WHERE stc_id = 5`? (Just checking that there's definitely only one result, plus wondering if selecting other columns with the "*" is confusing things, though I can't possibly see how it can be, really...)

Comment: The TOP part is not useful but explicitly listing the output columns fixed the issue. But I still have no rational explanation, check my update #2.

Comment: That's flat-out weird. Especially when selecting from a single table, where there can't be duplicate column names. I certainly can't explain it. Might even be an actual bug somewhere in the Microsoft code. Can you narrow it down to a column? i.e. can you reproduce it by selecting all the columns explicitly, `SELECT stc_id, stc_id_ute, stc_utente, ...`? And if you can, does it go away when you remove some of the columns? (I'd suspect the `ntext` ones, but that's only a hunch...)

Comment: You are right! Removing the 3 ntext columns, it works. I'm puzzled.

Comment: My guess would be that it's a bug when retrieving NTEXT column values in ADO. It may even be specifically related to the actual values in your NTEXT columns. It may be that if you update to later versions of whatever components you're using (ADO, .NET framework, etc.) that the problem simply disappears. I suspected the NTEXT values because they're the weirdest, i.e. the ones least often used in production systems, plus big and binary enough to show bugs (possibly memory overwrites) in the Microsoft code.

Comment: @MattGibson, you are definitely right, check my fourth (and hopefully last) update. Why don't you express this in an answer so that I can mark it as final and name you my hero? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the results you're seeing as we've investigated further, it seems as though the problem stems from the `NTEXT` columns that you're selecting implicitly with your `SELECT * ...` (but not using.)

As you've noted, there are [occasional hints on the web](http://p2p.wrox.com/sql-server-2000/3211-cant-pull-data-ntext-field-into-recordset.html#post78234) that there at least used to be problems retrieving large binary fields earlier than the end of the SELECT list when using ADO. (As soon as you linked to that article I did have a vague memory from the dim and distant past that I'd seen that advice before too.)

I'd suspect you may be using an older version of ADO, and that this problem may have been fixed in later releases.

Given that in this particular case you don't actually want to retrieve the values from the `NTEXT` columns, you should simply limit your `SELECT` list to the values you actually need, and everything should work fine.

Note that it's generally considered best practice to avoid the use of `SELECT *` except for quick, ad-hoc queries. Explicitly selecting the columns you need has several benefits. For example, in this case, even if your `SELECT` had worked perfectly, you'd still have been retrieving the potentially large amounts of data in your `NTEXT` fields (possibly across the network) from your database only to discard it without using it...

Note also that in [KB article 317016, "How To Read and Write BLOBs Using GetChunk and AppendChunk"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/194975), there's some "suggestions for using BLOBs with ADO", including:

> - Select the BLOB columns last. Select individual fields, not "*".

Comment: Awesome investigation Matt! I also updated the title to make it easier for other users to find out about this nasty bug. I'm using SQL Server 12.0.2269 and ADO 10.0 on Windows 10.